# What is the meaning of 'arc' as in "arc of a movie" or "arc of someone's character"?

Tags: vocabulary

Examples:
Preet Bharara: "In any arc in a movie, when someone treated his or her spouse badly, you want to see that person pay for that later."

"The arc of his character over the three stories is how he becomes humanized..."

I've looked at definitions of arc and didn't see a good/precise match:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/arc

Comment: Check the definition of [_story arc_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/story-arc?s=t) from the same source.

Comment: Think of it as the trajectory, or course, of the arrow of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **arc**([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arc)): (in a novel, play, or film) the development or resolution of the narrative or principal theme.
>
> *‘his transformation provides the emotional arc of the story’*

See also the definition of **'story arc'** on **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Story_arc)**:

> "A story arc is an extended or continuing storyline in episodic
>   storytelling media such as television, comic books, comic strips,
>   boardgames, video games, and films with each episode following a
>   narrative arc".

Comment: I asked you this yesterday, but please don't answer questions that the OP could have answered immediately and conclusively form himself by looking the word in question up in a dictionary or other general reference. It's not fair to the users of the site who have to clean up after such questions.

Comment: Did you not see the OP's last sentence?

Comment: I did. In fact, that's what frustrated me about the question. "I checked a dictionary and nothing matched" and "well, here's the exact answer you need straight from a dictionary". Also the "story arc" reference to Wikipedia would have been found by anyone who'd even typed those words into a search engine. This person did not put any real effort in before asking others to do work on his behalf. That's what frustrates me, and I don't want to encourage more of the same. Your answer is correct and helpful to OP,  but damaging to the site overall. We're not here to reprise the OED.